# Insufficient privileges when using create user in procedure Oracle

Tags: oracle

I try to create user and grant for them some privileges. I try to create without using procedure:

```
CREATE USER User1 IDENTIFIED BY password;
```

It works fine.
But for example, i have thousands of users. So I created a procedure to do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CreateUser AS 
BEGIN
FOR u IN ( SELECT id FROM User )
 LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER User_'||d.id || ' IDENTIFIED BY password';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON UserInfo_'||d.id||' TO User_'||d.id;
 END LOOP;
END
```

But it throws an error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

How can I handle this problem? Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: The reason is, inside a PL/SQL block you have only the privileges which are granted **directly** to you. Privileges which you received via a role (e.g. `DBA`) do not apply inside a PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the user running the procedure has the privileges to create users.

Assuming the user that will run the procedure is MyUser, you need to run :

```
GRANT CREATE USER to MyUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your SQL is directly (i.e not in a procedure ) but not working from a procedure/function it means that you have the Grants through a role. For a statement to work in a procedure or a function we need direct Grants and not through the role.

You can check that you have the Create user by a role by doing the following and trying your SQL, if it fails it means you have access through a role.

```
SET role none;
CREATE USER User1 IDENTIFIED BY password;
```